# Peewee ORM. Генерация запроса с переменным числом условий

Tags: python, peewee

Есть форма для поиска записей в БД. Как в Peewee можно сгенерить запрос вида: `SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM table WHERE field1 == 'value1' AND field2 LIKE '%value2%' AND field3 LIKE '%value3%'`?

Количество условий в запросе заранее неизвестно.

Answer (score 0):

Условия можно собирать "паравозиком" - они соединяются через AND.

```
params = [
(MyTable.column2 > 2), (MyTable.column1 == 'value1'), ...
]

select = MyTable.select(...)

for param in params:
    select = select.where(param)
```

[вот тут в коде селект собирается](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/b684dde9a1fb574d5cd13d3ae0b10287f5850d6a/peewee.py#L2279)

Comment: я пытался сделать подобным способом, но в вашем примере число полей известно, а у меня нет - я не знаю сколько полей формы будет заполнено.

Comment: Params - любой генератор, число полей любое

Comment: а как добавлять  значения в список param? У меня там условия идут: if len(self.lineName.text()) != 0: (добавить условие)

Comment: Append если список

Comment: пробовал так, добавил два значения в params - File "C:\Python364\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2567, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: row value misused

Comment: .sql(): 'SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."poet_id", "t1"."name", FROM "verse" AS "t1" WHERE (("t1"."poet_id" = ?) AND ("t1"."name" LIKE ?))', [63, '%Строка%']